# Creating graph with plotly using node.js and Passing array in axis

Tags: arrays, plotly

I want to make a simple graph. Here is the code in node.js from plotly official documentation.

```
 equire('plotly')(username, api_key);
 var data = [
  {
    x: ["2013-10-04 22:23:00", "2013-11-04 22:23:00", "2013-12-04 22:23:00"],
    y: [1, 3, 6],
    type: "scatter"
  }
];
var graphOptions = {filename: "date-axes", fileopt: "overwrite"};
plotly.plot(data, graphOptions, function (err, msg) {
    console.log(msg);
});
```

Here, i want to pass an array in x axis.The line is given below where i want to change.
**x: ["2013-10-04 22:23:00", "2013-11-04 22:23:00", "2013-12-04 22:23:00"],**

I have tried this way.

```
xx = [];

for (i = 1; i < 100; i++) {

            xx[i] = i;

}

var data = [
  {
    x: xx,
    y: [1, 3, 6],
    type: "scatter"
  }
];
var graphOptions = {filename: "date-axes", fileopt: "overwrite"};
plotly.plot(data, graphOptions, function (err, msg) {
    console.log(msg);
});
```

But code is not working given above.Please can anyone suggest me how to solve this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can see a graph getting generated, but what is the actual problem?

Comment: Blank Graph is generated. The problem is that i could not get the value of x axis when i  passed x axis value through  array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your code and I am able to get the xaxis. PFB the screenshot of the graph generated. I think you need to scroll down a bit to see the xaxis in the plotly online editor.

[image]

Moving on, I you are still not able to see the `xaxis`, I would suggest you set the below layout properties, where you can configure the `xaxis`. Refer the link here to go to the plotly official documentation.

```
var layout = {
  xaxis: {
    visible: true,
    range: [1, 100],
    dtick: 1
  }
}
```

In the above code I configure the `xaxis` to better suit the data provided.

```
var plotly = require('plotly')('username here', 'API Key Here');
xx = [];
yy = [];
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

  xx[i] = i + 1;
  yy[i] = y + 1;

}

var data = [{
  x: xx,
  y: yy,
  type: "scatter"
}];
var layout = {
  xaxis: {
    visible: true,
    range: [1, 100],
    dtick: 1
  }
}
var graphOptions = {
  layout: layout,
  filename: "date-axes",
  fileopt: "overwrite"
};
plotly.plot(data, graphOptions, function(err, msg) {
  console.log(msg);
});
```

I changed the yaxis values too, inorder to generate a better looking graph. Please let me know if this fixes your issue!

Comment: Thanks. It works finally. after changing the layout properties.

Comment: I didn't find the close option !